# trying to use jaxp : java obj -> xml node -> xslt -> display html

Tags: java, xml, servlets, xslt

I'm having kind of a weird problem I can't really figure out. I'm writing a web application, and I have a strategy for rendering the html which is giving me problems.

I have a group of objects with an asXML() method that returns an org.w3c.com.Node obj. That node has some html marked up as CDATA; I want to pass the entire node to an xslt stylesheet that will render the html the way I want it.

I wrote a junit test case that seems to work properly...meaning when I print it out on the console, it gives me the output I want

```
String sTransformedHtml = XMLUtils.runXmlTransform(sStylesheetPath, myNode);
```

a snippet of output:

```
<h1>This is a test description</h1>
<p>it uses some nice <em>markdown</em> formatting.</p>
```

yet when I try to call that same method in the same way from a servlet, I a) get escaped <, >, &, etc and b) the stylesheet seems to have been bypassed. In other words, the html markup created by the stylesheet itself has been omitted(not shown in example).

```
&lt;h1&gt;This is a test description&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;p&gt;it uses some nice &lt;em&gt;markdown&lt;/em&gt;    formatting.&lt;/p&gt;
```

Is there something inside the tomcat container that does char escaping? I've checked to make sure the stylesheet exists and everything else I could think of.

The function example I showed returns a string...I thought I might have better results if that func returned a node...but I ran into other annoying issues. for example, This is one of the html tags in the xslt template that should appear in the output :

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_id" value="{$myId}"></input></form>
```

but for some reason the output from the transform does not close the input tag....

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_id" value="2652"></form>
```

with all of this, I am considering just bagging the obj -> xml node -> xslt -> display html approach.

Just wondering if a) the approach itself sucks, b) have any of you ever dealt with this situation, and c) is there something simple I'm missing?

thanks,
jw

Comment: With HTML 4 as well as HTML5 the `input` element is an empty element and the proper markup syntax is `<input>` and not `<input></input>` so the result you get is fine if your aim is to create HTML output to parsed by an HTML parser. If you want XML output you need to change the `xsl:output` `method` to `xml`.

Comment: Check the HTML validator's output for http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.arcor.de%2Fmartin.honnen%2Fhtml%2Ftest2015030102.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices, it indicates that the syntax `<input></input>` is not valid HTML 4. So if your XSLT processor is supposed to create HTML to be parsed as text/html it is doing the right thing when it serializes an HTML `input` element without an end tag.

Comment: thanks...I got it to work for the moment by using saxon instead the default transfromerFactory. I also did a few other things...the func I showed above now takes in an Elements instead of a Node which allows for a few more methods, I also added the Result.PI_DISABLE_OUTPUT_ESCAPING pi. All of this stuff is kind of problematic, and I'm realizing this approach may need rethinking